# How to set culture in Web API 2 compatible with async/await?

Tags: async-await, asp.net-web-api2, culture, synchronizationcontext, http-accept-language

I have a REST service that generates string messages with currencies and dates, so I need the right culture to be set up. Messages are produced in different steps that runs between asynchronous operations.

Web API will set the culture coming in the `Accept-Language` header if such feature is configured in the Web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

After some testing it seems that the culture got by Web API this way is consistent across async/await operations. I wonder if it will behave the same way when on self-host...

However, I would like to know how to change the culture of the request arbitrarily in a way that flows correctly in the `SynchronizationContext` used by the host. I think it should be possible because as I said, the one adquired from the `Accept-Language` header using `enableClientBasedCulture="true"` seems to flow correctly.

For example, `AspNetSynchronizationContext` flows it through `HttpContext.Current`, so if `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and/or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` are manipulated, their culture may change after an `await`. So this way is not safe for async/await.

What I am looking for is not the [culture awaiter from Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/), but the way of forcing Web API to change the request's culture to something else.

I have tried with a delegating handler, changing the `Accept-Language` in the request message, but it seems too late and it has no effect on `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and/or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

Is there a way of doing this in a safe async/await way?

Comment: Why don't you pass the culture to your code instead of relying on some singleton?

Comment: Because I expect it to be a cross cutting concern. Otherwise I would have to pass the culture in each method, and set the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties of the `Thread` in the header of each method.